# How to export images to excel from MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

There was a function previously xlswritefig for this purpose but now in newer verions of matlab, it works no more. I need to export my plots from matlab to excel sheets that have been used to generate those plots.

Answer (score 1):

xlswritefig is not is part of Matlab but is [available separately](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24424-xlswritefig).

[The source is available on GitHub.](https://github.com/michellehirsch/xlswritefig)

See [this answer](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/427988-how-to-send-out-a-figure-using-plot-in-matlab-to-an-external-excel-file-when-r2017a-version-is#answer_345244).